# android intents and callbacks

Tags: android, callback, android-intent

I'm going through the tutorials for android and something about intent/activity interaction is confusing me. In Javascript whenever there is an ajax call we define how the results should be handled along with the ajax call and we can use different callbacks for different ajax calls throughout the application lifecycle. In android starting an activity with an intent and handling the passed back results are decoupled, at least that's how it's done in the tutorial and there is only a single point of entry for how the results are handled so it's hard to perform on the fly handling of results without messing with the main entry point. I can easily imagine some complex logic that could make the switching inside the main entry point into a horrible mess. Is this a fundamental android architectural thing or is there another way to do things with actual callbacks instead of switch statements in a single entry point?

Comment: `In Javascript` There's your mistake right there. This isn't javascript. In fact, it's probably about as far away from javascript as you can get.

Comment: @Falmarri: How's that a mistake? Programming patterns are an abstraction that often show up in different programming languages. Being far from Javascript does not preclude a language from having patterns that appear in Javascript.

Comment: Your mistake is learning a language/framework by comparing it to another framework. You're going to end up writing javascript code in android instead of writing good android code.

Comment: Your can't think of the application as a single page that performs actions. Every action (intent) is a separate activity that can come from anywhere and be in any state. You are responsible for threading these intents together to form the workflow in your application. In JS you can spawn any number of AJAX calls and do something when its done. The equivalent JS architecture for Android would be the AJAX call actually going to the page to do work then navigating to the previous one again when completed

Comment: @Falmarri: Really? I guess all those cognitive scientists saying people learn by metaphor and comparison must be getting millions for nothing. I program in a functional style and it's clean style in any language so save the venom for somebody else unless you have an actual answer to my question.

Comment: It's not venom. Java is not even close to a functional language, and the Android framework simply doesn't even support functional programming. You can't force it to be what it's not. You could program in assembly all day but that doesn't help you trying to learn Java.

Comment: Could you be more specific about which elements you're finding cumbersome? Also, any switch statement can be trivially turned into a hash table lookup and callback dispatch if you so desire.

Comment: @methodin: The Ajax calls like activities return results that are handled at some later point. You are making it sound more complicated than it is. The async nature of Ajax and intents spawning activities is what's similar between the two but Ajax calls are not all handled with a single switch statement.

Comment: @adamp: Yes, that's what I'd like to do. Where do I go to learn more about this.

Comment: @adamp I think what is cumbersome is the need for a switch statement at all.  This is analogous to an `onClickListener`.  I personally find it a lot cleaner to provide a callback function using an internal class for each clickable item, than to have a single onClickListener for all clickable items and use a switch statement to see which one was clicked.  This is somewhat style/personal preference though.

Comment: @Falmarri: I didn't say functional programming. I said functional style, i.e. as little mutability as possible with small procedures instead of gigantic class hierarchies with mutable state throughout.

Comment: @Mayra: Your way sounds closer to what I was originally thinking. Do you have a reference to the android docs talking about doing what you just said.

Comment: @davidk01 No, that is not possible for activity results.  Only for click listeners.  See my answer below for my best suggestion for activity results.

Comment: @Falmarri The concept of a callback function is rather universal, and certainly not unique to javascript.  The implementations of it may vary greatly by language, but they almost all, including Java, have some way of doing it.

Comment: @davidk01 No. The activity does not "return" data in the classic sense. It re-starts the activity with parameters. Every time you start an intent your entire application can die. There is no coupling aside from the same shared application space. And again you just re-iterated my point. AJAX does NOT spawn activities, it calls a child HTTP request that returns data. If anything Android is like the classic web. There is no PARENT/CHILD relationship like AJAX.

Comment: @methodin: I don't really follow. Even the android docs make the obvious comparison between activities spawning activities and the stack-like nature of each activity sitting above the one that spawned it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that you are limited to a single location for receiving responses that an activity has finished.  It would be nice if you could define a callback function for each, but that is not how it works.

In my experience though, you seldom have so many different destinations from a single activity that it is hard to manage.  Generally each page only leads to one or two other pages that you might care about getting results from.

You can do something like the following to cleanly separate your logic for each case:

```
void onActivityResult(int requestCode, ....) {
  switch(requestCode) {
     case Activity1:
        onActivity1Result(...);
        break;
     case Activity2:
        onActivity2Result(...);
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Davidk01 Wait, this was the answer?  I must not have understood the question.  You wanted to know if you could call other methods from the switch statement to clean your code up?

Comment: @Nick: It was the most reasonable answer. I was hoping to couple a callback with the intent at the activity spawning point but it looks like this is not possible. I think callbacks are a more natural way to program especially when GUI elements are involved. In languages that allow it I am used to building up callable structures and then calling them at the right time. From the chatter it looks like this is not possible in android and I'll have to stick with switch statements.

Comment: @davidk01: How many activities are you starting that you expect results from? That could be the real root of your problem. If you have more than 1 or 2 activities that you call with startActivityForResult, you probably should rethink your design to decouple your activities better.

Comment: @Davidk01 fair enough, just wanted to make sure.  I think that the opted to go against callbacks is because of the emphasis on decoupling the components.  I cannot envision (though, i'm not expert) how you'd structure a call back in a way that functions with purely uri based intent invocations.  I guess its something to think about.

Comment: @Nick: Usually when the framework allows callbacks it's easier to follow the application logic because as the user interacts with the application you can capture events and create closures that have access to the current state in the application that become callbacks which do the right thing when the event system calls them. Anyway I think without giving actual example code I can't make it any more clear. I think Java not having first class functions is just a bit of a constraint I'll have to get used to.

Comment: @david I took a look at some javascript to get an idea.  I see what you mean about getting access to state.  I'm trying to understand how you'd serialize the callback?  Is that possible?

Comment: @Nick Campion and @Davidk01 Java does do callbacks via (usually anonymous) inner classes.  These are possible for things like click handlers.  Since it is just a class, it could be serialized as necessary.  My guess is the difficulty in this case comes in the fact that the calling Activity can be killed and recreated during the time the called Activity is visible.  Its probably not impossible to create a callback model, but is significantly harder than for a simple click handler where everything is expected to stay in scope.

Comment: @Mayra: You're right of course. It was some newbie thinking on my part. After messing around some more with the framework and playing with the activity creation mechanics I think passing around bundles is probably the easiest way of handling the asynchronous nature of activities.

Comment: @Nick Campion: Javascript has closures so as long as you create a function that references existing variables outside the function scope those variable references will stick around. I guess the closest thing is Java is inner classes but I'm not enough of an expert to tell you how exactly they are related. But as Mayra mentioned Javascript often has the browser window that is constantly in scope and I don't think there is something similiar in the android framework other than maybe the main application process.

Answer (score 1):

Intents and Activities are designed to allow developers to develop re-usable, loosely coupled components.

I understand that, when working internal between two activities that you are creating, the mechanisms can seem unnecessarily restrictive.  The restrictiveness is part of the open nature of the platform.  The same mechanism that you use to start an activity you own could start an Activity created by another developer or by the OS itself.

That being said, there are a plethora of options for passing information between activities.  It really depends what you are trying to accomplish.  I try to think of activities just that, activities from the users perspective.  I'm going to list some mechanisms for passing data and, if you'd like to further describe your application or need, I'll try to help you narrow the options down:

- Intent.putExtra
- startActivityForResult (I'm assuming you know this one)
- SharedPreferences
- Service
- ContentProvider

Comment: I was already thinking along the lines of Intent.putExtra but I'm not sure how self documenting this kind of code will be when there are a lot of parameters being passed back and forth between activities with Intent.putExtra. I was hoping to avoid parameter explosion by localizing the logic to the callbacks.

Comment: @davidk01 Since the intent extras need to be accessed in at least the calling and called activity, its not possible to have them localized in a single function.  Your best bet is to declare them as static consts in one, consistent place. I usually did that in the called activity with a consistent naming scheme like STRING_EXTRA_FOO and INT_EXTRA_BAR to be self documenting.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that you do not have to start a new activity for a background process without its own screen such as an Ajax call - you can use `AsyncTask` instead which allows for a javascript style callback.